# `plt.figure` leads to empty output

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to resize the plot of the example of a [Stacked Bar Graph](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html) from the matplotlib website. However, when I introduce e.g. `plt.figure(figsize=(30,10))` the output test.png is only a white image. How can I resize a Stacked Bar Graph in Matplotlib?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 5
menMeans = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)
womenMeans = (25, 32, 34, 20, 25)
menStd = (2, 3, 4, 1, 2)
womenStd = (3, 5, 2, 3, 3)
ind = np.arange(N)    # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars: can also be len(x) sequence

p1 = plt.bar(ind, menMeans, width, yerr=menStd)
p2 = plt.bar(ind, womenMeans, width,
             bottom=menMeans, yerr=womenStd)

plt.ylabel('Scores')
plt.title('Scores by group and gender')
plt.xticks(ind, ('G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5'))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 81, 10))
plt.legend((p1[0], p2[0]), ('Men', 'Women'))

plt.figure(figsize=(30,10))

plt.savefig('test.png', dpi=300)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plt.figure(figsize=(30,10))` line should be before the `plt.bar` line.

Comment: This does the job. Thank you!